# Dagger 2 and Android Databinding Adapter: cannot be provided without an @Inject or @Provides

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-databinding

I'm using Android's Databinding library and Dagger 2. I wanted to make use of a DatabingAdapter in displaying my images in the RecyclerView. I have my Picasso instance created using Dagger and I have to inject it inside the DatabindingAdapter that I created. I followed this tutorial [here](https://philio.me/using-android-data-binding-adapters-with-dagger-2/) and I'm getting the error that Picasso cannot be provided without @Inject or @Provides annotated method. Here's my code (classes are simplified to focus more on this issue, I got Picasso already working before).

#### AppModule.java

```
@Module(includes = {AndroidInjectionModule.class, NetworkModule.class, ViewModelModule.class})
public class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @AppScope
    Picasso picasso(App app, OkHttp3Downloader okHttp3Downloader) {
        return new Picasso.Builder(app.getApplicationContext())
                .downloader(okHttp3Downloader)
                .indicatorsEnabled(true)
                .build();
    }
}
```

#### BindingModule.java

```
@Module
public class BindingModule {
    @BindingScope
    @Provides
    ImageBindingAdapter provideImageBindingAdapter(Picasso picasso) {
        return new ImageBindingAdapter(picasso);
    }
}
```

#### BindingComponent.java

```
@BindingScope
@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class, modules = BindingModule.class)
public interface BindingComponent extends androidx.databinding.DataBindingComponent {
}
```

#### AppComponent.java

```
@AppScope
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class, ActivityBuildersModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(App app);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(App application);

        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

#### ImageBindingAdapter.java

```
public class ImageBindingAdapter {

    private final Picasso picasso;

    public ImageBindingAdapter(Picasso picasso) {
        this.picasso = picasso;
    }

    @BindingAdapter(value = "url")
    public void loadImageUrl(ImageView imageView, String url) {
        if (url != null && !url.trim().isEmpty())
            picasso.load(Constants.ENDPOINT + url).into(imageView);
    }
}
```

And here's what the error is.

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.squareup.picasso.Picasso cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
com.squareup.picasso.Picasso is injected at
com.ralphevmanzano.themoviedb.di.modules.BindingModule.provideImageBindingAdapter(picasso)
com.ralphevmanzano.themoviedb.databinding.ImageBindingAdapter is provided at
androidx.databinding.DataBindingComponent.getImageBindingAdapter()
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you try to Inject your BindingAdapter? Databinding can automatically see it from xml file.

Comment: @p.alexey because I'm trying to use the Picasso instance that I built using dagger in the BindingAdapter

Comment: You can just do `Picasso.get()` instead of picasso inside ImageBindingAdapter.

Comment: @p.alexey I was wondering before about that too, will that method get the instance that was built in Dagger? also this is my bad really, tried using constructor injection in the binding adapter just now and it worked.

Comment: @p.alexey I just compared the instances of Picasso by logging `picasso.toString()` and `Picasso.get().toString()` and they got different hex codes. When I checked the source code I found out I have to set singleton instance in picasso by calling `Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso)`. Now using `Picasso.get()` returns the same instance as an injected `picasso` object, great! and thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing `@Inject` annotation from your `ImageBindingAdapter` class

```
@AppScope
public class ImageBindingAdapter {

    private final Picasso picasso;

    @Inject
    public ImageBindingAdapter(Picasso picasso) {
        this.picasso = picasso;
    }

    @BindingAdapter(value = "url")
    public void loadImageUrl(ImageView imageView, String url) {
        if (url != null && !url.trim().isEmpty())
            picasso.load(Constants.ENDPOINT + url).into(imageView);
    }
}
```

Adding `@Inject` tell dagger to add this class to graph, then you can add your scope annotation to your class to tell in which scope this class is added.

ps : You can remove your `BindingModule`class

Comment: @Ralph I have the same issue, already add Inject to binding adapte constructor but still got same error, any clue?